# How do I switch between phone and email authentication on the WooCommerce checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce

I have several payment methods in **WooCommerce**, for example **cryptocurrency payment** method and **fiat** (*dollar payment or any other method other than cryptocurrencies*).

I want that when the user **clicks on crypto payment**, he will **only have to validate his email and the phone validation field will not be displayed for this user**, but **if he chooses dollar payment** (fiat payment or any other payment other than crypto payment), he **will have to Both phone phone and email validation** should be done together and the **payment options will not be activated until the validations** are done. (The buyer should not be able to pay without e-mail validation in both payment methods and e-mail and mobile validation in payments other than cryptocurrencies, and **if the validation was not done, the payment button should not be displayed**)

**dollar payment or any other method other than cryptocurrencies:**

> [image: dollar payment or any other method other than cryptocurrencies]

**cryptocurrency payment:**

> [image: cryptocurrency payment]

**Let me explain a little more:**

The customer adds the product(s) to his shopping cart and goes to the checkout page, where there are several fields to enter the buyer's details, such as name, email, etc. Now the buyer chooses one of the payment methods, if The payment method chosen by the buyer was cryptocurrencies, only email validation should be done and there is no need to enter the phone field, but if the buyer had chosen the dollar payment method, he should do both email and phone validation.